# I would like to switch workspaces by using the mousewheel

Tags: desktop, workspace

There is a very simple option that would help me greatly in order to achieve more producivity. I would like to be able to press the metakey and scroll down, and instantly go to the previous workspace, and metakey and scroll up to do the opposite. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the Multitasking View with either <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> or by clicking on the Multitasking View item in the Applications Menu or the Dock, you can scroll between workspaces with the mousewheel.

Comment: You can set a hot corner for it too